# Getting the 3x3 groups in a sudoku board with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make a program that checks if a given sudoku board is valid (solved correctly).
Also want to do it using linq however I find it hard to come up with a solution to get all the 3x3 groups from the board.
I want to get them as a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` because of how I wrote the rest of the code.
Here is my solution so far :

```
public static bool IsValidSudoku(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> sudokuBoard)
        {
            if (sudokuBoard == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
                .Select(lineCount => Enumerable.Range(0,9)
                .Select(columnCount=>sudokuBoard
                    .ElementAt(columnCount)
                    .ElementAt(lineCount)
                    ));

            var groups = //this is where I got stuck
                
            return columns.All(IsValidGroup) &&
                sudokuBoard.All(IsValidGroup) &&
                groups.All(IsValidGroup);
        }

        static bool IsValidGroup(IEnumerable<int> group)
        {
            return group.Distinct().Count() == group.Count()&&
                   group.All(x => x <= 9 && x > 0)&&
                   group.Count() == 9;
        }
```

Performance is not important here.
Thank you for any advice!

Comment: You probably need two enumerable ranges 0-2 for the x and y indexes of the group (i.e. which 3x3 square you want), and then two more ranges 0-2 to collect the elements within the group.

Comment: But you need to access the squares by index really, so it might be simpler to have your board as Lists not Enumerables, or a 2D int array. (Or I guess that's the 'performance not important' point?)

Comment: I am testing arrays that contain 9 arrays representing the lines of the sudoku board so to access by index I can just use ElementAt. I just can't wrap my head around the logic of doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two enumerables to choose which 3x3 group you're selecting, and then you can use .Skip and .Take to take runs of three elements to fetch those groups.

```
var groups = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).SelectMany(gy =>
             Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(gx =>
                 // We now have gx and gy 0-2; find the three rows we want
                 sudoBoard.Skip(gy * 3).Take(3).Select(row =>
                     // and from each row take the three columns
                     row.Skip(gx * 3).Take(3)
                 )
             ));
```

This should give you an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`s as requested. However to pass each group to IsValidGroup you'll have to flatten the 3x3 `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` into a 9-long`IEnumerable<int>`s, e.g. `groups.Select(group => group.SelectMany(n => n))`.